React использует VDOM или Fiber?
У меня небольшие вопросы по тому, как все таки работает react. Прочла собственно статью про VDOM, да и до этого слышала про это, но один из комментаторов сказал, что это устаревшая штука и сейчас используется Fiber. И вот вопрос, что в итоге используется то? Просто внятного ответа как то не удалось найти...

Одно другому не мешает, строится Virtual DOM дерево описывающий некоторый узел. А вот для управления изменениями и внесения этих изменений в реальный DOM используется Fiber (процесс называется Reconciliation). Возможно вы читали статью, в которой управление изменений в Virtual DOM было не таким, как в Fiber.

спасибо большое, за пояснение!!!
